# Missing $ inserted error

Tags: math-mode, errors, formatting

All the below equations work in CodeCogs but I am still getting an error for them in Texmaker. `\begin{equation}` is line 501

```
\begin{align}
P(c)= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} P(c\vert\vec{x_i})

\mu_{c,j} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\frac{P(c\vert\vec{x_i})}{nP(c)})x_{i,j}

(\sum_{c})_{j,k} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\frac{P(c\vert\vec{x_i})}{nP(c)})(x_{i,j} - \mu_{c,j})(x_{i,k} - \mu_{c,k})

 P(c\vert\vec{x_i}) = \frac{P(\vec{x_i}\vertc)P(c))}{\sum_{i=1}^{k}P(\vec{x_i}\vertc)P(c)}

P(\vec{x_i}|c) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(\sum_{c})}} exp(- \frac{1}{2}(\vec{x_i} - \vec{\mu_c})^T \sum_{c}^{-1}(\vec{x_i} - \vec{\mu_c}))
\end{align}
```

Error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.501

I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
! Display math should end with $$.
<to be read again>
\par
l.501
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. There must be no empty line after `\begin{equation}` or `\end{equation}` .etc. In addition, `equation` is not the right tool for this. Use `align` instead, for example. What is `codecogs`?

Comment: online latex equation editor https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

Comment: its still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the missing `\\`s to terminate the lines, I strongly suggest you read the `amsmath` package documentation.

I could not find the `vertc` symbol anyway, which I translated in `\vert c`.

Do not leave empty lines inside math;

I also manually adjusted the height of the brackets, and substituted `exp` with the proper operator `\exp`.

I also substituted `(\sum_c)_{j,k}` with `\sum_c{\mathstrut}_{j,k}` to get rid of the parenthesis

I hope to have caught everything

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
P(c)= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} P(c\vert\vec{x_i})\\
\mu_{c,j} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Bigl(\frac{P(c\vert\vec{x_i})}{nP(c)}\Bigr)x_{i,j}\\
\sum_{c}{\mathstrut}_{j,k} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\Bigl(\frac{P(c\vert\vec{x_i})}{nP(c)}\Bigr)(x_{i,j} - \mu_{c,j})(x_{i,k} - \mu_{c,k})\\
 P(c\vert\vec{x_i}) = \frac{P(\vec{x_i}\vert c)P(c))}{\sum_{i=1}^{k}P(\vec{x_i}\vert c)P(c)}\\
P(\vec{x_i}|c) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sum_{c}}} \exp\Bigl(- \frac{1}{2}(\vec{x_i} - \vec{\mu_c})^T \sum_{c}^{-1}(\vec{x_i} - \vec{\mu_c})\Bigr)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You beat me by 2 seconds

Comment: @CarLaTeX but still working on it :) ahhaha the fastest of the west

Comment: You'll beat egreg!

Comment: @Moriambar: Hm, the coughing never stops

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I understand: with all the allergies I sometimes start sneezing all around :)